# p4 perl - how to add a file into p4 repository?

Tags: perl, addition, perforce

I was reading this p4 perl official page:
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/02_perl.html

But I can not find a library to add a file. I would guess something like:

runadd(), runAdd(), or RunAdd(). But exactly which one is correct? How many arguments does it take?

And lastly, why does not the p4 perl offcial page have it listed?

Could someone post a sample code that can add a file to p4 repository?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like it's:

```
$p4->Run('add', $filename);
```